# Live reload using grunt-contrib-connect and grunt-contrib-watch

Tags: javascript, node.js, gruntjs, grunt-contrib-watch, grunt-contrib-connect

I am new to nodeJS and grunt. I have this Gruntfile in this project and I want to do live reload for all the html files in my project, so that I do not have to refresh my browser all the time to detect new changes. Somehow I encounter error with the following code:

```
module.exports = function (grunt)
{
    // Project configuration.
    grunt.initConfig(
    {
        // Task configuration.
        jshint:
        {
            options:
            {
                curly: true,
                eqeqeq: true,
                immed: true,
                latedef: true,
                newcap: true,
                noarg: true,
                sub: true,
                undef: true,
                unused: true,
                boss: true,
                eqnull: true,
                browser: true,
                globals: {}
            },
            gruntfile:
            {
                src: 'Gruntfile.js'
            },
            lib_test:
            {
                src: ['lib/**/*.js', 'test/**/*.js']
            }
        },
        connect:
        {
            server:
            {
                options:
                {
                    hostname: 'localhost',
                    port: 80,
                    base: 'src',
                    keepalive: true,
                    livereload: true
                }
            }
        },
        watch:
        {
            options:
            {
                livereload:true
            }
        }

    });

    // These plugins provide necessary tasks.
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-connect');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');

    // Default task.
    grunt.registerTask('default', ['connect', 'watch']);


};
```

It seems that when I start 'grunt default' it would not execute task watch because during connect it is keepalive.

I will be grateful if any1 can explain to me why I have this error when JSHint check my code and suggest a solution to this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your `watch` task does not have any tasks or files. For it to work with `grunt-contrib-connect`, you need to include more than just the `livereload` option, like so:

```
watch: {
    options: {
        livereload: true
    },
    taskName: {    // You need a task, can be any string
        files: [   // Files to livereload on
            "app/js/*.js",
            "app/templates/*.html"
        ]
    }
}
```

Or alternately:

```
watch: {
    taskName: {
        options: { // Live reload is now specific to this task
            livereload: true
        },
        files: [   // Files to livereload on
            "app/js/*.js",
            "app/templates/*.html"
        ]
    }
}
```

All files that match the glob patterns here should then work as you're expecting. You do not need to specify a `tasks` parameter here if you are just live reloading these for the browser.

Also, if you are going to be using your `connect` server alongside `watch`, you should remove the keepalive parameter as it is a blocking task and can prevent executing the `watch` task:

```
connect: {
    server: {
        options: {
            port: 8080,
            base: 'src',
            livereload: true
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Like your suggestion, after removing keepalive parameter, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need `node:true` in your jshint config, take a look at this example [.jshintrc](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/jshintrc).

For the watch and livereload, you need to specify which files to watch, and what tasks to execute in your Gruntfile, again, take a look at this sample [Gruntfile](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js).

For example like this:

```
 watch: {
      coffee: {
        files: ['<%%= config.app %>/scripts/{,*/}*.{coffee,litcoffee,coffee.md}'],
        tasks: ['coffee:dist']
      },
    }
```

In this example, you specify a glob as `files` option and whenever that files change the according tasks are run.

Comment: sorry I do not quite get it. Are you talking about another file (jshint.config) or are you talking about the options under jshint in the Gruntfile above?

Comment: you can have either, in your case you have it in your Gruntfile above. @Zackery

Comment: ok I get jshint working already, 2k plus error :P. But it does not solve the live reloading problem

Comment: what is your live reloading problem update your question @Zackery.

Comment: When I update my html files I cannot see the changes without refreshing my browser. What I wanted to achieve is whenever I edit and save the html files I should be able to see the changes I did in the browser(localhost) without doing anything on the browser.